# Truetype font spacing?

Tags: text, fonts, directx, rendering, truetype

I'm in the process of vectorizing true type fonts to render them as Direct3D primitives. So far I've successfully managed to extract the glyphs using GetGlyphOutline, and render them as linelist primitives. Anyway, on to the spacing...

How can I find out the spacing between characters, or how/where is it determined?
Clearly the spaces vary with non-monospace fonts.

Is there a GDI+ or other windows function call to determine the spacing?

Comment: I asked a simular question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42737846/true-type-font-format-pen-position-advance-width-and-kerning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about direct3d, but if your just after the metrics they are stored in the typefaces kerning table; [GetKerningPairs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will tell you the correct placement for sets of character pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the advance width of the glyphs (stored in the [hmtx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/hmtx) table of the font, or [vmtx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/vmtx) for vertical text). Via GDI, which it sounds like you are using rather than DirectWrite, you can use:

1. [GetCharABCWidthsI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcharabcwidthsi) if you already have an array of glyph ids. This approach can support any character in Unicode including extended CJK and newer additions like Egyptian heiroglyphics, not just the lower basic multilingual plane.
2. [GetCharWidth32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcharwidth32w) for character widths - limited to the basic plane, but the simple option.
3. Call [GetGlyphOutline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getglyphoutlinew) with GGO_METRICS and use gmCellIncX. This returns more fields than you're probably interested in though.

Kerning is an *additional* optional adjustment to the nominal advance, such as in the word "AVATAR" where 'A' and 'V' would be shifter closer for aesthetic purposes.